# Angular `build` throw error for externals decaled with `webpack`

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-externals

In my angular, I am loading `jquery` from extranal and it works. But, after the `build`, I am getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`  . My build downloads the `jquery`, mind you.

Question: How can I map the `jquery` with my build?

index.html:

```
<script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.8.2/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
          "jquery": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"
        }
      }
    </script>

 <script>
      System.import("single-spa");
      System.import("jquery");
    </script>
```

webpack config ( it works well locally )

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    jquery: ["jQuery"],
  },
};
```

Note: After the build, if I run it in server, I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.xeH2 (main-es2015.3ee70c890346f45d7daa.js:2)
    at l (runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1)
    at Module.zUnb (main-es2015.3ee70c890346f45d7daa.js:2)
    at l (runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main-es2015.3ee70c890346f45d7daa.js:2)
    at l (runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1)
    at t (runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1)
    at Array.r [as push] (runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1)
    at main-es2015.3ee70c890346f45d7daa.js:2
```

My server try to download the `jquery` from an external source.

[image: here is the network in server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

When webpack externals are an object, the keys are the name you import in your code, and the values are the name of the module in the runtime environment.

The "runtime environment" used by the webpack bundle could either be global variables or the SystemJS module registry, depending on your webpack config's [output.libraryTarget](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget). The behavior of [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals) changes for different libraryTargets.

If your libraryTarget is `"system"` (recommended for SystemJS loading), `"umd"`, or `"amd"`, then the bug here is that the name of the module in SystemJS module registry is `jquery`, but your webpack config expects it to be `jQuery`. SystemJS module names are case sensitive.

If your libraryTarget is unspecified or `var`, then webpack will look for a global variable called `jQuery`. If you're using the systemjs `amd.js` extra, then jQuery will not be created as a global variable. But if you are not using amd.js, then jQuery will be created as a global variable.

### Possible fixes

1. Change your webpack config to expect the runtime environment to provide `jquery` instead of `jQuery`. This will only work if the webpack libraryTarget is `system`, `umd`, or `amd` (as explained above).

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    externals: {
        jquery: "jquery",
    },
};
```

That webpack config is equivalent to providing externals as an array of strings:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    externals: ["jquery"]
};
```

2. Remove the SystemJS amd.js extra from your index.html file. This will ensure that jQuery is created as a global variable. Then make sure the webpack config's libraryTarget is either unspecified or `var`.

### Further diagnosis

To diagnose the issues here, you can run the following in the browser console:

```js
await System.import('jquery')
```

This will print how the jquery module was loaded by SystemJS. You should click on the logged value to expand it and see the keys. You should see jquery functions that you're familiar with it.

Comment: Looks good. my try is, I would like to keep all my `systemjs` in to global. where  it need to be consumed by other `angular` single-spa can consume, instead of keeping their own copy. for this case what it your advice?